# How to route all requests to HomeController

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to route all requests (excluding a few exceptions) to my HomeController

So regardless of whether I go to `/home/index` or `/about/` or `/sport/soccer` it directs to the Home Controller (but the URL remains in the browser, so I don't want to use Redirect)
Decorating the controller initially works, but it won't allow the exceptions

```
[Route("{*url}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
```

I don't know how to achieve this

My end goal would be something like

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "exception01",
    pattern: "{ Error}/{errorCode?}"
);

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "exception02",
    pattern: "{ MySecretController }/{code}"
);

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{ *uri} GOES TO {Home}/{Index}"
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need only one action (Index as example), then you can try set route for Action:

```
public class HomeController
{
    [Route("{*url}")]
    public IActionResult Index(string url)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is good but doesn't seem to allow any exceptions. As I wrote in my OP, I still want to define an ErrorController (or route)

Answer (score 0):

If your exceptions only has these two cases, then you can add `regex` conditions to the attribute of `[Route("{*url}")]` to determine.

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("{*url:regex(^(?!Error$|MySecret$).*$)}")] 
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
        }
    }
```

Here is the test result:

[image]